# How to assign value to a variable using an execute statement

Tags: dynamic, mariadb

I need to execute code along this line

```
select @a := id from B limit @i ,1
```

However mysql doesn't allow a variable to be passed in limit so I tried two other things

```
select @proc := concat('select @a := id from B limit ', @i, ',1');
prepare stmt from @proc; 
execute stmt;
```

This gives an error, as does

```
select @proc := concat(' id from B limit ', @i, ',1');
prepare stmt from @proc; 
select @a := execute stmt;
```

Note that I have not declared @a before anywhere, but I am lost at this moment and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: it's mariaDB 10.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
MariaDB [_]> SET @`a` := NULL,
    ->           @`proc` := CONCAT('SELECT @`a` := `B`.`id`
    '>                              FROM `B`
    '>                              LIMIT ', IFNULL(@`i`, 0), ', 1
    '>                             ');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`proc`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

MariaDB [_]> EXECUTE `stmt`;
+------------------+
| @`a` := `B`.`id` |
+------------------+
|               10 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT @`a`;
+------+
| @`a` |
+------+
|   10 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

Another option without using [CONCAT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/concat/) function.

```sql
MariaDB [_]> SET @`a` := NULL,
    ->           @`i` := IFNULL(@`i`, 0);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> PREPARE `stmt` FROM 'SELECT @`a` := `B`.`id`
    '>                            FROM `B`
    '>                            LIMIT ?, 1
    '>                           ';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

MariaDB [_]> EXECUTE `stmt` USING @`i`;
+------------------+
| @`a` := `B`.`id` |
+------------------+
|               10 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT @`a`;
+------+
| @`a` |
+------+
|   10 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: what is the purpose of ifnull statement?

Comment: btw your idea of using ``' worked so i have accepted the answer , but can you explain why you used IFNULL

Comment: @avz2611: [IFNULL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/ifnull/) is to assign a default value to the variable `@\`i\`` in case it is NULL.

Comment: ah all right thanks , i guess i should get into the habit of using back ticks now :P

Comment: @avz2611: Check [Identifier Qualifiers](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/identifier-qualifiers/).

Comment: i tried using 'using' before but i passed @a as variable instead of @i which was giving me some error